Python - Take Pprint Export and Convert to Pandas DataFrame
I am NEW to python and am learning it to pull data into Power BI. By new, I mean this is my first project. My current use case is to extract data regarding tasks from Asana. I have successfully copied, pasted, and adjusted the python code that Asana offers and am getting data regarding my tasks. I am struggling with how to take that data and turn it into a dynamic table using pandas so that I can pull it into Power BI. We don't have an enterprise license with Asana, which is why I need to use python instead of their connector. I have already imported pandas and have that available.
Here is the code to pull the tasks from Asana (sensitive info modified):
import asana
from asana.rest import ApiException
from pprint import pprint

configuration = asana.Configuration()
configuration.access_token = 'Abcd123'
api_client = asana.ApiClient(configuration)

tasks_api_instance = asana.TasksApi(api_client)
opts = {
    'project': "123456789",
    'opt_fields': "name,actual_time_minutes,assignee,assignee.name,"
                  "custom_fields,custom_fields.name,custom_fields.display_value,"
                  "due_on,start_on,"
                  "permalink_url"
}

try:
    tasks = tasks_api_instance.get_tasks(opts)
    for task in tasks:

        pprint(task)
except ApiException as e:
    print("Exception when calling TasksApi->get_tasks: %s\n" % e)

Here is a sample of the output that I get when I run it:
{'actual_time_minutes': None,
 'assignee': {'gid': '1104899036650576', 'name': 'Jane Doe'},
 'custom_fields': [{'display_value': None,
                    'gid': '1207268873906857',
                    'name': 'Estimated time'},
                   {'display_value': None,
                    'gid': '1207268873683694',
                    'name': 'Priority'},
                   {'display_value': 'Closed',
                    'gid': '1207268873683699',
                    'name': 'Status'},
                   {'display_value': 'https://dev.azure.com/clientsite',
                    'gid': '1207269260215808',
                    'name': 'Link to DevOps'},
                   {'display_value': None,
                    'gid': '1207277291413677',
                    'name': 'Sprint'},
                   {'display_value': '4265',
                    'gid': '1207269541980519',
                    'name': 'DevOps ID'}],
 'due_on': '2024-04-05',
 'gid': '1207277618607073',
 'name': 'Update Javascript on this Thing',
 'start_on': None}
{'actual_time_minutes': None,
 'assignee': None,
 'custom_fields': [{'display_value': None,
                    'gid': '1207268873906857',
                    'name': 'Estimated time'},
                   {'display_value': None,
                    'gid': '1207268873683694',
                    'name': 'Priority'},
                   {'display_value': 'On Hold',
                    'gid': '1207268873683699',
                    'name': 'Status'},
                   {'display_value': 'https://dev.azure.com/clientsite',
                    'gid': '1207269260215808',
                    'name': 'Link to DevOps'},
                   {'display_value': None,
                    'gid': '1207277291413677',
                    'name': 'Sprint'},
                   {'display_value': '3867',
                    'gid': '1207269541980519',
                    'name': 'DevOps ID'}],
 'due_on': '2023-12-12',
 'gid': '1207277735170286',
 'name': 'Create Workflow to Do This',
 'start_on': None}
{'actual_time_minutes': None,
 'assignee': None,
 'custom_fields': [{'display_value': None,
                    'gid': '1207268873906857',
                    'name': 'Estimated time'},
                   {'display_value': None,
                    'gid': '1207268873683694',
                    'name': 'Priority'},
                   {'display_value': 'New',
                    'gid': '1207268873683699',
                    'name': 'Status'},
                   {'display_value': 'https://dev.azure.com/clientsite',
                    'gid': '1207269260215808',
                    'name': 'Link to DevOps'},
                   {'display_value': None,
                    'gid': '1207277291413677',
                    'name': 'Sprint'},
                   {'display_value': '4354',
                    'gid': '1207269541980519',
                    'name': 'DevOps ID'}],
 'due_on': None,
 'gid': '1207277611759913',
 'name': 'Write the Script for this Thing',
 'start_on': None}
{'actual_time_minutes': None,
 'assignee': {'gid': '1104899036650576', 'name': 'John Doe'},
 'custom_fields': [{'display_value': None,
                    'gid': '1207268873906857',
                    'name': 'Estimated time'},
                   {'display_value': None,
                    'gid': '1207268873683694',
                    'name': 'Priority'},
                   {'display_value': 'Closed',
                    'gid': '1207268873683699',
                    'name': 'Status'},
                   {'display_value': 'https://dev.azure.com/clientsite',
                    'gid': '1207269260215808',
                    'name': 'Link to DevOps'},
                   {'display_value': None,
                    'gid': '1207277291413677',
                    'name': 'Sprint'},
                   {'display_value': '4353',
                    'gid': '1207269541980519',
                    'name': 'DevOps ID'}],
 'due_on': None,
 'gid': '1207277863543561',
 'name': 'Go Do This Important Thing',
 'start_on': None}

As you can see, there are multiple records that are returned. The values that I need to grab from this are: name,assignee.name,Status,Estimated time,actual_time_minutes. I need to build a DataFrame for this data and I need to essentially run each record returned through a loop so that it is a row. The data returned will change though so I can't give it the values that it should display. I need to tell it which 'column' in the returned data to use instead.
I appreciate ALL help, but as I'm trying to learn this, I would also appreciate any explanations on why I should do it a certain way.
Using a separate query, I was able to successfully build a dummy test table to get the idea of building a table with pandas. However, I am at a loss on how to get from my data above to something that replicates the results of this.
import pandas as pd
data = [['Alex',10],['Bob',12],['Clarke',13]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Name','Age'])
df.loc[len(df)] = ['Barbara',25]
print (df)

Results from pandas test:
      Name  Age
0     Alex   10
1      Bob   12
2   Clarke   13
3  Barbara   25

Process finished with exit code 0


You don't want to pprint() the task as that just shows you on the console something nice.  You want to filter your tasks to get something you will load into pandas.

Conceptually, you don't want to pprint() as that just does something for display (usually). Instead, you probably want to just reshape tasks into something that just includes your desired keys and values and then pass that list into pandas.DataFrame()
I would start with:
import asana
import pandas

configuration = asana.Configuration()
configuration.access_token = "Abcd123"
api_client = asana.ApiClient(configuration)
tasks_api_instance = asana.TasksApi(api_client)

opts = {
    "project": "123456789",
    "opt_fields": "name,actual_time_minutes,assignee,assignee.name,"
    "custom_fields,custom_fields.name,custom_fields.display_value,"
    "due_on,start_on,"
    "permalink_url"
}

results = pandas.DataFrame(
    {
        "name" : task["name"],
        "assignee_name" : (task.get("assignee") or {}).get("name"),
        "status" : next(row["display_value"] for row in task["custom_fields"] if row["name"] == "Status"),
        "estimated_time" : next(row["display_value"] for row in task["custom_fields"] if row["name"] == "Estimated time"),
        "actual_time_minutes" : task["actual_time_minutes"]
    }
    for task in tasks_api_instance.get_tasks(opts)
)
print(results) # just to show it is working

That should give you:
                              name assignee_name   status estimated_time actual_time_minutes
0  Update Javascript on this Thing      Jane Doe   Closed           None                None
1       Create Workflow to Do This          None  On Hold           None                None
2  Write the Script for this Thing          None      New           None                None
3       Go Do This Important Thing      John Doe   Closed           None                None


Thank you! I learned much more from this than you may realize too!
